# How to install ctypes on Mac with Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

```
(.env) ➜  ~ easy_install ctypes
Searching for ctypes
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ctypes/
No local packages or download links found for ctypes
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ctypes')


(.env) ➜  ~ pip install ctypes
Collecting ctypes
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ctypes
```

I use easy_install or pip to install ctypes,but they all failed.

So I download ctypes-1.0.2-AMD64.zip to install

```
(.env) ➜  ctypes-1.0.2 sudo python setup.py build
Password:
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Configuring static FFI library:
cd build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/libffi && env CFLAGS='' '/Users/wyx/Downloads/ctypes-1.0.2/source/libffi/configure' 
env: /Users/wyx/Downloads/ctypes-1.0.2/source/libffi/configure: Permission denied
Failed
```

It failed again.

```
(.env) ➜  ctypes-1.0.2 cd source/libffi
(.env) ➜  libffi ll
total 680
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    1080 May 15  2007 LICENSE
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff   15851 May 15  2007 README
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    3365 May 15  2007 aclocal.m4
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff   44911 May 15  2007 config.guess
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff   33113 May 15  2007 config.sub
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff  208082 May 15  2007 configure
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    8716 May 15  2007 configure.ac
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    4310 May 15  2007 fficonfig.h.in
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    2125 May 15  2007 fficonfig.py.in
drwxr-xr-x@  4 wyx  staff     136 Apr  7 00:30 include
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    7416 May 15  2007 install-sh
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 wyx  staff     646 Apr  7 00:30 src
```

Then I try change the permission of **configure** in 777 .But I fail again with a strange prompt.

```
(.env) ➜  ctypes-1.0.2 python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Configuring static FFI library:
cd build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/libffi && env CFLAGS='' '/Users/wyx/Downloads/ctypes-1.0.2/source/libffi/configure' 
env: /Users/wyx/Downloads/ctypes-1.0.2/source/libffi/configure: No such file or directory
Failed
(.env) ➜  ctypes-1.0.2 cd source/libffi
(.env) ➜  libffi ll
total 680
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    1080 May 15  2007 LICENSE
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff   15851 May 15  2007 README
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    3365 May 15  2007 aclocal.m4
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff   44911 May 15  2007 config.guess
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff   33113 May 15  2007 config.sub
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 wyx  staff  208082 May 15  2007 configure
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    8716 May 15  2007 configure.ac
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    4310 May 15  2007 fficonfig.h.in
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    2125 May 15  2007 fficonfig.py.in
drwxr-xr-x@  4 wyx  staff     136 Apr  7 00:30 include
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 wyx  staff    7416 May 15  2007 install-sh
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 wyx  staff     646 Apr  7 00:30 src
```

Who can help me to solve it or Is there any other Python lib can instead of **ctypes** which can be **installed more easier** ?

Comment: ctypes is a standard module, you shouldn't need to install it. But I don t use a Mac, I use Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Python 2.5 [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes) is part of Python's standard library. Just import it:

```
import ctypes
```

No need to install anything.

Comment: Thanks ,you solve my problem.The course I learn use Python 2.4 and before that I didn`t use this library.