# How do I fix the fact that Pip3 not working for Linux Mint?

Tags: python, linux, pip

when i type in pip3 install ctypes it says:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ctypes

i've already tried upgrading pip but that did nothing and i'm very annoyed

Comment: `ctypes` is a built-in no? Shouldn't that come with the install without having to add an additional dependency?

Comment: `ctypes` should be a builtin package, so pip is unecessary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install ctypes on Mac with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457439/how-to-install-ctypes-on-mac-with-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

ctypes is a built-in module in Python and does not need to be installed using pip. It is possible that the error you are encountering is due to a typo or a misunderstanding of the purpose of the ctypes module.

If you are trying to use the ctypes module, you can simply import it into your Python script without needing to install it. Here is an example of how you can use ctypes:

import ctypes

## Define a function pointer type

AddFunc = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)

## Define a simple function

def add(x, y):
return x + y

## Create a function pointer to the add function

add_func_ptr = AddFunc(add)

## Call the add function through the function pointer

result = add_func_ptr(3, 4)

print(result) # Output: 7

If you are trying to install a package that depends on the ctypes module, it is possible that the package is not compatible with your version of Python or your operating system. In this case, you may need to look for alternative packages or solutions that meet your needs.

In any case, the ctypes module does not need to be installed separately using pip.

Comment: please format your answer in readable way.